# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, app-config

I am using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpHost"] to read a value from the app.config file in my business logic layer, but the value returned is always null, even though the key exists and it has a value, Does any one know why?

App.config file in BLL:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="smtpHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
</appSettings>
```

I added the same thing to the web.config file.

And I try to get;

```
var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpHost"];
```

Comment: Can't reproduce; for me it's working fine.

Comment: Read This Answer as Well. I think you may help this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330143/configurationmanager-return-null-instead-of-string-values/61882895#61882895

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct (i have tested), you need to make sure that your app.config file is in your main project (exe).

Comment: Also check if your <appSettings> section is in <configuration> section

Comment: How can I be sure that app.config file is in the main project?

Comment: Namespace of your class must be the same as the project in which you have  your app.config.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I defined it in the web.config file in the UI layer.But I called in the unit test method of the Business layer. It worked correctly when called from the UI layer